# Как загрузиться в FreeBSD со сломанным загрузчиком?

Tags: freebsd, загрузка, boot, mbr

У меня есть диск (HDD, SSD, флэшка - что угодно) с установленной на него FreeBSD. Я каким-то образом сломал загрузочный код (первые 446 байт MBR) на диске, и теперь моя FreeBSD даже не пытается загрузиться.

Однако я знаю, что разделы на диске не повреждены, и все данные, кроме куска MBR, на месте. Как мне загрузиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы имеете дело с "классической" 512-байтной загрузочной записью (MBR в стиле DOS) - всё довольно просто.

DOS-like MBR состоит из 3 частей: первые 446 байт несут в себе непосредственно код загрузчика (bootcode), который умеет передавать управление загрузкой компьютера загрузочному сектору, находящемуся в одном из разделов диска; следующие 64 байта описывают "основные" разделы диска (4 по 16 байт); оставшиеся 2 байта - это сигнатура `55h AAh`.

Если код загрузчика был [стёрт](https://gist.github.com/rc5hack/b8f130b4bc1ae26307df), как-то повреждён, затёрт нулями или заменён другим загрузчиком, не знающим ничего про FreeBSD, но таблица разделов осталась на месте - загрузиться в установленную на один из разделов FreeBSD можно, просто воспользовавшись загрузчиком любой другой FreeBSD для старта.

- Начните загрузку любой BSD-like операционной системы (я проверял этот метод на FreeBSD 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 9.2 и Frenzy 1.4) с другого носителя - HDD, CD, с USB-флэшки, через сеть по PXE, через virtual media посредством BMC/KVM, etc.
- В процессе загрузки выберите опцию "Escape to loader prompt" на экране загрузчика (она будет под номером "6" в старых дистрибутивах FreeBSD, "3" в FreeBSD 9, "8" в Frenzy)
- Теперь выгружайте ядро "чужой" FreeBSD, в загрузчике которой находитесь, и его модули, с помощью команды `unload`
- Найдите дисковое устройство, на котором находится FreeBSD, в которую необходимо загрузиться (обычно это что-то вроде `disk0s1a`) с помощью команды `lsdev`
- Выберите это устройство "основным" ("current") для загрузчика, дав команду `set currdev="disk0s1a"`
- Перечитайте `loder.conf` с вашего диска (там могут быть критичные для правильной загрузки хаки, вроде подключения модулей ядра для работы с сетевыми картами) командой `read-conf boot/loader.conf`
- И, наконец, загрузите вашу ОС командой `boot-conf`

Когда ваша недоступная для самостоятельной загрузки FreeBSD загрузилась, останется только починить её загрузчик. В своём случае я использовал `sysinstall`, пункт Custom -> Partition, <kbd>W</kbd>, `<Yes>`,  `BootMgr` ("Install the FreeBSD Boot Manager"), `<OK>`, <kbd>Q</kbd>, `<Exit>`, `<Exit Install>`. Однако эта утилита объявлена устаревшей с момента выхода 9.0-RELEASE и убрана из базовой системы с момента выхода 10.0-RELEASE. Есть и альтернативный способ восстановить загрузчик, воспользовавшись резервной копией, хранящейся в `/boot` (за подсказку спасибо @dile):

```
# gpart bootcode -b /boot/mbr /dev/yourbootdevice
```

Comment: `gpart bootcode -b /boot/mbr ada0`

Comment: @dile спасибо, как раз то что нужно! проверил, добавил в ответ.